# Role based views in extjs4 mvc

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

My application has different views for different roles like (admin or standard user).I don't know how can i implement it with extjs4 MVC. Examples of extjs4 documentation  consider that application has only one role like standard user so they create one app.js file that manage application but if application has many roles i don't know how can i implement different views for different users.
One matter is i have two app.js files in the application and after i get user role in the server i load appropriate app.js file to use appropriate views,controllers,models,stores and so on.
Is this matter true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather standard question that comes up so many times and the answer is always the same:

- Access Control belongs to the Server where no user can manipulate it
- Simply don't provide a View / a model / a controller to a user where he has no access to

With that in mind it doesn't matter if you have one app or ten.

And because Access Control is nothing that belongs to the frontend there is no implementation within ExtJS.

**Update -> Hide UI elements**

A ready to go approach would be the use of `Ext.direct`. This provide the application with a API that can be modified based on custom access of the current user and can then be checked by the frontend.

HowTo:

Create the API based on the user session and check on the Clientside like

```
if(Booking) {
   if (Booking.Create) {
       // has access
   }
}
```

or as one line

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    hidden: !(Booking && Booking.Create)
}
```

This is just a simple example how easy this could be done!

**update**
This [Link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-streamline/index.html) helped the op

Comment: I noticed from your answer that i should have two app.js file for my application in server side. Is it true?

Comment: @taher that would be a option if you have only two roles. But if you have more roles you may need to rethink your design. Meaning: you may not be able to use just precompiled libs. Your server will need to hand out specific libs only to users with the appropriate access or combine them at the time the user logs in or provide the fullapp that hide UI elemnts for parts the user didn't have access to.

Comment: Thanks, For case that application has more roles can you give me example about hiding UI elements for parts the user didn't have access to?

Comment: Thanks @sra for your answer, But i don't know what is Booking in your code! can you explain about it?

Comment: @taher That is a example API

Comment: thanks for your help, please import this link to your answer to be helpful http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-streamline/index.html